# Уточнение или перечисление?

Tags: пунктуация

Есть предложение:

Однако, к сожалению, речь идет о поставках десятков, сотен, в лучшем случае – нескольких тысяч (,) регуляторов данного типа…

Нужна ли указанная запятая? В Нацкорпусе встретила как случай с запятой, так и без... Мне все же кажется, что запятая здесь не нужна, она создает ненужное разделение словосочетания *нескольких тысяч регуляторов*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Запятая не нужна.**

Сравним: Однако, к сожалению, речь идет о поставках **десятков, сотен,  нескольких тысяч** регуляторов данного типа (здесь выделены **однородные члены)**. В заданном предложение "в лучшем случае" относится к одному из однородных членов.

**Похожий пример с однородными членами**: Сомнения и протест могут вызвать в ней лишь **негодование**, в лучшем случае ― брезгливое **сожаление**. [И. Ф. Анненский. Вторая книга отражений (1909)]

Answer (score 4):

Вы правы, разрывать запятой словосочетание  *нескольких тысяч регуляторов* неправильно, это даже смысл предложения делает не очень понятным.